# function using exists function in R

Tags: r, function, exists

I am trying to create my own function to avoid the duplication of data object and I created following code:

```
check_data_exist <- function(data){
  if(exists("data")==TRUE){
    z=y
  } else
    x = seq(1,10)
}
```

However, my function is not doing anything and also not giving me any error message. I would be grateful for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let that I found the error that braces were missing. I corrected as follows (just in case someone is struggling like me)

```
check_data_exist <- function(data){
  if(exists("data")==TRUE){
    z=y
  } else{
    x = seq(1,10)
  }
}
```

Anyway, many thanks.

Comment: If output is already logical, it's just `if (exists("data"))`.